# ComboBoxIndexchanged and linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using a database called babaEntities in C# and have the following code:

```
        db = new babaEntities();
        comboBox1.DataSource = from x in db.Tipusok
                               orderby x.TipusNev
                               select new { x.TipusNev, x.TipusID };
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TipusNev";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "TipusID";
```

TipusID is integer, TipusNev is nchar

```
    private void frissites()
    {
            var termekek = from x in db.Termekek
                           where x.TermekNev.StartsWith(textBox1.Text)
                           where x.TipusID == (int?)comboBox1.SelectedValue
                           select new
                           {
                               x.TermekNev,
                               x.EgysegAr,
                               x.Raktaron,
                               x.Egysegek.EgysegNev
                           };
            termekekBindingSource.DataSource = termekek;
    }
```

TermekNev is nchar, EgysegAr is int, Raktaron is int, Egysegnev is nchar. (ternekek is the datasource for a datagridview)

Whenever I try to run the frissites() method in ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged event like this:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frissites();
    }
```

it gives the following error, "InvalidCastExpection was unhandled by user code - Specified cast is not valid", and it doesn't run - but if I run it in the TextBox1_TextChanged method, it's completely fine, even if I just run the .exe file. I have been at this for hours. Can anyone help? I hope my problem is understandable.

(Basically, I want to be able to narrow the data with the textbox and have it only search for certain types (=tipus) from a combobox.)

[image: Picture of the error window]

[image: View detail]

[image: Value of ComboBox1.SelectedValue]

Comment: [This is a picture of it](http://i.imgur.com/aJIB7lc.jpg) (It doesn't really say anything more, no error message, instead of it running I get this.)

Comment: [This is in the View Detail](http://i.imgur.com/iCcoKGD.jpg)  
[Full 'stacktrace'](http://i.imgur.com/Q99jII5.jpg)

Comment: Try casting or int.tryParse() the value before you define termekek

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedValue is
"TipusID=10
TipusNev="eledel""

Comment: Oh wow, yes that probably was it, I put that same line before the DataSource and Displaymember line, it is now in 3 places, but I will find which one is the right, but it works now!

(Martin, I tried your version, but it also gave an error message (a different / longer one)

Answer (score 0):

I can spot one suspicious cast here:

```
where x.TipusID == (int?)comboBox1.SelectedValue
```

it may be valid, but let's make sure that this is NOT the culprit by changing it to something like:

```
where x.TipusID == GetTipusID(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
...
private int GetTipusID(object selected)
{
    if (selected == null) return -1;

    int value;
    if(Int32.TryParse(selected.ToString(), out value)) return value;
    else return -1;
}
```